# A section in a document for things that you haven't time to think in which section of the document to place them

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I have a 'live' document (a document that is constantly updated) that is in fact a long list of hyperlinks, with multiple sections like "Foos" and "Bars". There is also a "Various" section in its end, for links that cannot be placed in any other section.

Sometimes I discover a new link on Internet that is interesting/useful enough to be added to  this list, but I don't have time to think about in which section to place it.

So I need one another section after "Various", and I'm not sure how to name it. Something like "Unsorted", but I'm not sure "Unsorted" is a really good name for it, that is, not sure this name really makes sense.

Any ideas?

Comment: Who is going to be reading this document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unsorted is fine.

When writing, think of your audience.  Who is going to read this document? The purpose of headings is to help your reader navigate the document.  The "unsorted" section is not much use for anyone except you - as a reminder that you need to sort these links.

Comment: @user90726  I think my real doubt is "why use English".  I would title such a section "unsorted" because English is my first language.  Why not use your first language?

Comment: Well, at first glance there are at least three reasons. But I think there is only one of them that really does matter. This is that I never really liked the county where I was born, its history, its ethics, its language, and so on. And at the same time, I regularly visit bbc.com and read their articles about the English history, and I have read Le Morte d'Artur and I have a list of the other works that consists Matter of Britain.

Comment: I try to use English for my documents as often as possbile.

Comment: That is very sad.  A country cannot have ethics, only people have ethics, and there are good and bad people everywhere.  A language is a only as beautiful as the artists and poets who use it, and there are great artists and poets everywhere. And I could start on some of the darker history of Britain, but I fear I'd bore you.

Comment: "Only people have ethics, and there are good and bad people everywhere" - this is, of course, truth. But the proportion is different in every historical period of time. Look, I'm Russian from Russia. I live here, in one of the two largest and richest cities. What you see now in Ukraine is only the tip of an iceberg. This is not because of Putin. This is because of the people here.

Comment: I teach and am friends with lots of Russians.  And Russia is the Russia of Tchaikovsky,  Prokofiev, Tolstoy, Chekov etc etc

Answer (score 0):

"**Miscellaneous**" is the commonly-used category for things which do not fit in any other category. It is often abbreviated as "*misc.*".

Comment: OP already has a "Various" category for links that do not fit in any other section. They're looking for the name of a section where they can dump the (useful) links in because they *don't have the time* to put it in any other section.